# How to Get Specific number from Narration?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get Number(3035222061) from the below to seperate row. Can u guide me how to get that using Macro or Excel formula?. ( I want to do that becoz daily i need to copy and paste the same thing for 200 line items.)

```
X-BORDER WIRE FT||CHARGE||USD 593.79||53.8425000||Fvg:GILMAN||PERG8047356553||S0902 TWRDS||CONSIDERATION FOR PATEN||3035222061||TRN REF NO:B01APAF131224JUB
```

Comment: Is the line of data in a single cell? or is it in form of CSV? If latter one, you can use `||` as delimiter.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - Entire Narration will be in Single Cell and it will be in same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is always the same format and the lenght of number is fixed, use this:

```
=ABS(MID(A1,SEARCH("TRN",A1)-12,10))
```

Considering your text data is on A1.

Put formula in B1.
The `MID` and `SEARCH` formula gets the value.
I only use `ABS` in case you need it as number.

Comment: Is there is change in Format will it work ???

Comment: basically as long as the sequence where the word `TRN` appears remains constant and the length of `Number` is constant then it will work.